# E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main [dupli]

Tags: java, android

When I run my application something went wrong
and I got this error:

> 05-09 09:23:21.215 9003-9003/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
>   05-09 09:23:21.544 9003-9003/com.example.aryan.lb_minisquad_re2 D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
>   05-09 09:23:21.545 9003-9003/com.example.aryan.lb_minisquad_re2 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                     Process: com.example.aryan.lb_minisquad_re2, PID: 9003
>                                                                                     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.aryan.lb_minisquad_re2/com.example.aryan.lb_minisquad_re2.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.Window.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
>                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2236)
>                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
>                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
>                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
>                                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
>                                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
>                                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
>                                                                                      Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.Window.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
>                                                                                         at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:2072)
>                                                                                         at com.example.aryan.lb_minisquad_re2.MainActivity.(MainActivity.java:19)
>                                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
>                                                                                         at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1606)
>                                                                                         at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1066)
>                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2226)
>                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
>                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
>                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
>                                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
>                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
>                                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
>                                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
>                                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698) 
>   05-09 09:23:24.923 9003-9003/com.example.aryan.lb_minisquad_re2 I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 9003 SIG: 9

And Here's My MainActivity.java

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) //TODO solve runtime problem(E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

}
TextView tvnum = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TV_num);//creating object of TextView
 public int id = 100;//id is first number of tv num
Button btnMin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnMIN); //creating object of  btnMin to avoid of exceptions
  public void onbtnMinClicked()//calling onClick listener of btnMin
  {
      String num =  tvnum.getText().toString();//num is value of tvnum
      num = String.valueOf(--id);//setting num one less than self(what btnmin have to do
      tvnum.setText( num );//setting num again to the tvnum
  }
}
```

Comment: Well, something went wrong.

Comment: This cannot be solved without a stacktrace and code. So unless you supply that, as ThingyWotsit said, something went wrong

Comment: `I get this error` Which error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your instantiation must be inside a method check the following and under setContentView method

```
TextView tvnum =null;
Button btnMin=null;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) //TODO solve runtime problem(E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
 tvnum = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TV_num);//creating object of TextView
int id = 100;//id is first number of tv num
btnMin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnMIN);
}
```

Comment: so I can't make my variables public in onCreate method and I can't use it in onClick method.

Comment: Check my updated  Answer, this is how you can make them public
So you can use them anywhere that you want inside the class